# Shooting projectiles towards mouse position in Unity 2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, projectile-physics

I'm currently creating a scrip that handles the projectile movement and it's almost where I want it to be. Currently the script correctly instantiates the projectiles, moves the projectiles towards the mouse and deletes them off screen, but the speed of the projectile is not constant (faster or slower depending on how close the mouse is to the player) and after the projectile is fired, it follows the position of the mouse until it flies off screen.

```
public class LetterController : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<GameObject> letters = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject letterPrefab;
    public float letterVelocity;
    Vector3 direction;
    void Update()
    {
        direction = Input.mousePosition;
        direction.z = 0.0f;
        direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(direction);
        direction = direction - transform.position;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject letter = (GameObject)Instantiate(letterPrefab, transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
            letters.Add(letter);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject goLetter = letters[i];
            if (goLetter != null)
            {
                goLetter.transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * letterVelocity);
                Vector3 letterScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(goLetter.transform.position);
                if (letterScreenPosition.y >= Screen.height || letterScreenPosition.y <= 0 || letterScreenPosition.x >= Screen.width - 20 || letterScreenPosition.x <= -20)
                {
                    DestroyObject(goLetter);
                    letters.Remove(goLetter);
                }
             }
          }
       }
   }
```

I tried moving everything from `Update()` into a separate function called `Shoot()` and called that from `Update()`. I tried putting `Vector3 direction` in its own Vector3 function and calling it in `goLetter.transform.Translate`. I also tried using `LateUpdate()`. Nothing I've tired has made any significant changes to how the projectile interacts in Unity. I'd like to have the projectiles move at a constant speed and not follow the cursor but rather travel in a straight line anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is two fold:

First, when you spawn an object, that should be the last the current script interacts with it. From that point forward, the new object should control its own behavior. You need to modify your projectile to handle its own movement.

The second is the use of `Vector2.MoveTowards()` instead of `Translate()`.

For projectiles that don't track the mouse, like a bullet:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FixedProjectile : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed=6.0f;

    void OnStart()
    {
        target=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void Update() {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position =Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,target.position,step);
    }
}
```

For projectiles that track the mouse, like a guided missile:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseGuidedProjectile : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed=6.0f;

    void Update() {
        target=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position =Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,target.position,step);
    }
}
```

For projectiles that track a specific target, like a guided missile with target lock, simply remove the target line from Update() :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GuidedProjectile : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed=6.0f;

    void Update() {
        if(target!=null)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position =Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,target.position,step);
        }
    }
}
```

and set the target transform after you instantiate the object

```
GameObject missile = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
missile.target=GameObjectToTarget.transform;
```

Comment: In your ScreenToWorldPoint examples, it looks like `target` should be of type Vector2 instead of `Transform`.

Comment: You're right. I'll update when I get back to a computer. Code formatting is terrible on mobile

Comment: I applaud you for writing this on mobile. People like you who are so keen to help even through the horribleness that is mobile, is what keeps this community (and the world) moving forward. Thank you.

Comment: Fiancé is buying shoes. Found some time to fight with the formatting. Updated to vector2. Also corrected a copy paste error on the third class name

Comment: Note that *`First, when you spawn an object, that should be the last the current script interacts with it`* isn't necessarily true: there's an overhead on scripts having their own `Update()` methods. Having a *central* script that runs `Update()` and tells other objects to perform frame-tick-code is more efficient. But correctly organizing your software architecting to use that design pattern is too long for a comment.

Comment: Agreed. Bullets are also a prime opportunity for object pooling as well. Also they should track the ray to the position, not just move to its coordinates. But all of these performance improvements are beyond the scope of an answer to an entry level question. I think it's good to mention tho for the Asker to be able to dig into further.

Comment: I had been so confused for while. This really helped. Thanks!